# Itunes Connect does not list all localized languages for metatdata

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

My App has been localised for English (primary) plus Italian, Dutch and Spanish, but when I come to provide metadata for each in iTunes Connect the only options listed are as per the screen shot. According to the Apple there are 28 supported languages. How do I access them?

[image: Localization options screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might sound like a silly answer, but you need to scroll down. It is actually a longer list of languages, but this is not made clear in the UI. I have made this error myself.

You will find Italian and other languages after the Finnish language.

Comment: OMG I can't believe I didn't try that. You're right there are no visual clues that the list is longer. Thank you so much!